How to use height parameter in ttk.Button and other widgets?
I have a question.
How do I use height, font, and other common arguments ... in ttk.Button and other widgets?
Button1 = ttk.Button(root , height = 2 , width = 30 , font = "Tahoma 12 bold"  , text = "click me")


the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

I would recommend to check tkinter and ttk documentation.
About font from documentation:

Tk uses a list font name format, such as {courier 10 bold}. Font sizes
with positive numbers are measured in points; sizes with negative
numbers are measured in pixels.

About height:

Specifies a minimum height for the element. If less than zero, the
base image’s height is used as a default.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
